# How did I exchanged user and super user setups

Tags: restore

I loged in as a super user, and changed thenormal user setups. After normal login I just lost a lot of default setups. 
Any idea how can I restore it?

Comment: The `root` user and your user are different. Any settings you set on one user will be lost on another. Your question is rather vague and unclear.

Comment: I was logged in as a root user, and set tryed to fix xampp, and afterrestart my root directory , and setups changed.

Comment: Did you login as a regular user, or did you login as `root`?

Comment: The question is kind of vague. What did you change when you logged in as the root user? What did you expect to happen when you logged back in as a regular user? If you log into a gui as the root user, any changes you make will not be carried over to all the other users. It is advisable to log in as a normal user, and just use 'sudo' commands to do things adn make changes as the super user. That way your changes will persist. If you give me some specifics on what you would like to do I may be able to help more.

Comment: When I loged in as an user my desktop was cleared, and my chrome setups also lost, and also my terminal visual setups gone. And when i log in as a superuser, the terminal fetures comes back like the user 's should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings are applied to the X graphical interface (Gnome, KDE...) on a per-user basis.

Therefore, if you changed some setting while logged in as root (*), you won't find the same settings applied when logging in as another user.

(*) Side note: doing this is considered unsafe. Always log in to X as a unprivileged user, and escalate to root user whenever necessary.